# How can my friend access to MySql database and work/use it like I do?

Tags: mysql, xamarin.forms, mysql-workbench

I'm making a Xamarin forms app. Behind this app there is a MySQL database (Mysql-workbrench) witch only me could connect to. I would like that my friend (lives on a other location) could access this database and work with it using for using it in Xamarin.

Is there a way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, host the database on a public server that you can both access.

Comment: Witch public server do you propose to use?

Comment: Recommendations like that are specifically off-topic on SO.  Google "mysql hosting".